# Should I use a browser key or an Android key for the gmaps API?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created an Android key in the Google Developers Console. But I need to call the distance matrix API by a JSON-Call. Sadly, the API says that my call won't be accepted.

```
{
    "destination_addresses" : [],
    "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address XXXX, with empty referer",
    "origin_addresses" : [],
    "rows" : [],
    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Because of that, I've just created a browser key. But I can't set a referrer for security, because my call comes from the Android app.

Is this acceptable, or should I go another way?

Answer (score 1):

Android Key is to use in your App (Java code).
Make sure you did add enable the API : 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/maps_android_backend/overview

Make sure you did add the Package name and the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/key/0

Answer (score 0):

[Google Maps Distance Matrix API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key#types-of-api-keys) states:

> Google Maps APIs are available for Android or iOS apps, Web browsers, and via HTTP web services. APIs in each platform require a specific type of key. *The Google Maps Distance Matrix API will only work with a **Server key***. APIs of the same platform can use the same key.

Here's the [Server key](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490) description.

Regardless what the description of the Server key is, in your *[This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#using-google-maps-apis)* scenario, I think it would fall under the:

> It used to be possible to get this error if you used any of the web service APIs with a Browser key. **Requests to Web service APIs should be identified with a Server key. Switch your key type from a Browser key to a Server key.**

And seeing that the Google Maps Distance Matrix API is a Web service API, I would advise to follow what is actually suggested in the Official Google Documentation -- by using a Server key.

I'm not sure if this will be useful for you, but it is also actually mentioned in the [FAQs](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#using-google-maps-apis):

> **How do I resolve the error: "Browser API keys cannot have referer restrictions when used with this API."?**
>
> You are using any of the web service APIs with a Browser key. For **security reasons**, web service APIs need to use a Server key. Switch your key type from a Browser key to a Server key.

Cheers! :D

Comment: Mh, first I thought this would be correct, but when I'm using the credentials wizard on the Google Development Console to find out, which key is the right one for an Android App in use with the Distance Matrix, it recommends me to use the Android-API-Key. But this isn't working. I have to set the browser key additionally to call the Web-API. Maybe I have to call the Distance Matrix on another way? :/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm looking to do the same thing. Using native iOS or Android keys don't work for the Matrix API and using an IP restriction won't really work on mobile.